# button alignment under table not working in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this html code where by I have a table inside a div inside a container.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered" id="calctable">
    ....
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-suceess"></button>
</div>
```

I would like to move the button directly on the bottom right of the table similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE5hk.png).

I tried multiple ways to get what I wanted, but they dont work properly. I tried to use `float-right` class to float the button to the right. I tried to use `col-sm-offset-11`. Didn't work either.  Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Does the table have visible borders?

Comment: What you need is to place another div wrapping the table and button, set the width of this div to your desired width. Then put the button: `float: right`

Comment: @JuanR yes it does

Comment: @Jackson it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you want, the two examples below use a wrapper around your `table` and `button` elements :

```css
.col-sm-12 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrapper { width: 80%; }

table {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}


/* With flexbox (don't forget to add vendor prefixes) */

#test-flex .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#test-flex button { align-self: flex-end; }

/* With float */

#test-float button { float: right; }
.clear { clear: both; }
```

```html
<!-- With flexbox -->

<div id="test-flex" class="col-sm-12">

    <div class="wrapper">
      <table></table>
      <button>Button</button>
    </div>
    
</div>

<!-- With float -->

<div id="test-float" class="col-sm-12">

    <div class="wrapper">
      <table></table>
      <button>Button</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the thousand ways to do this :

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered" id="calctable">
        ....
    </table>
</div> 
<div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
    <button class="btn btn-success"></button>
</div>
```